# One-Hot Encode Features With Multiple Labels

Tags: r, autoencoder, one-hot-encoding

In python we can make One-Hot Encode Features With Multiple Labels
Example: https://chrisalbon.com/machine_learning/preprocessing_structured_data/one-hot_encode_features_with_multiple_labels/

I have a dataframe with several columns and last one is the Label.

This Label is a list like this (each line a new row):

```
Label
"A"
"B"
"C"
"D"
"A,B,C"
"A,C"
"D,B,A"
"D,C,B,A"
```

I try:

```
levels(data_Frame$Label)<-c("A","B","C","D")
New_data_Frame<-as.data.frame(decodeClassLabels(data_Frame$Label))
```

But What I get is:

```
A   B   C   D
1   0   0   0
0   1   0   0 
0   0   1   0 
0   0   0   1 
0   0   0   0 
0   0   0   0 
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
```

What I want is:

```
A   B   C   D
1   0   0   0
0   1   0   0 
0   0   1   0 
0   0   0   1 
1   1   1   0 
1   0   1   0 
1   1   0   1
1   1   1   1
```

Comment: try `library(qdapTools);mtabulate(strsplit(df1$Labels, ","))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to split the 'Labels' column by `,` and then use `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
+(mtabulate(strsplit(df1$Label, ",")) > 0) 
#     A B C D
#[1,] 1 0 0 0
#[2,] 0 1 0 0
#[3,] 0 0 1 0
#[4,] 0 0 0 1
#[5,] 1 1 1 0
#[6,] 1 0 1 0
#[7,] 1 1 0 1
#[8,] 1 1 1 1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A,B,C", "A,C", 
"D,B,A", "D,C,B,A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -8L))
```

Comment: Amazing is working, and it's so easy. I lost a week trying to get a solution and you 27 minutes after my post solved the problem.